# Protractor: ng-binding what does the ng stand for

Tags: binding, protractor

I'm using protractor and locators like `ng-bind` and I got curious.
What does the "ng" stand for?
I did a bit of hunting and didn't find the definition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about protractor, but this might be related to [Angular](https://angular.io/) which has "ng" in front of a lot its functions. For example: `ngFor`, `*ngIf`, and `ngClass`.

Also a lot of 3rd party angular libraries use `ng` to denote that they are angular libraries. For example [ng-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap), [ng-quill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-quill), and [ng-score-polygon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-score-polygon).

Note that `ng` was typically used for angularjs, `ng2` and `ngx` were typically used for angular 2 and newer. Now `ng` is typically used for angular2 because angularjs is in long time support and not maintained.

If this is not related to some angular testing tool within protractor, then I'm not sure what it could stand for.

Answer (score 0):

ng is short for A'ng'ular. I know, that it's not a great abbreviation but it is what it is. Since you are using Protractor, you must have come across additional locators like model, repeater etc, these utilises ng-model, ng-repeat. All built in functions of Angular uses this prefix.

Answer (score 0):

The prefix ng stands for "Angular;" all of the built-in directives that ship with Angular use that prefix. Similarly, it is recommended that you do not use the ng prefix on your own directives in order to avoid possible name collisions in future versions of Angular.

From the [FAQ](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq):

> Why is this project called "AngularJS"? Why is the namespace called
>   "ng"?
>
> Because HTML has Angular brackets and "ng" sounds like "Angular".